# How does OSGi bundle update work?

Tags: osgi

When a bundle is updated (say to fix a bug), what happens to other bundles that are currently using the one being updated?

Say that there are two bundles service and dao. Say that classes in service bundle are using classes in dao bundle when I issue command to update dao layer. Will the class in service layer using dao code get an exception?

---

Thanks for your [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4335798).

I meant to say updated with the same version.

> until a bundle refresh occurs which includes the dependent bundle.

Bundle refresh operation is invoked by the user updating the bundle, right? Say that when user invokes refresh to update dao bundle, a class in bundle service invoked a method on a class in dao layer... what happens in this scenario?

I found this blog post helpful:
http://solutionsfit.com/blog/2008/08/27/osgi-what-modularity-can-do-for-you-part-1/

From the post:

> If we simply replace the bundle with a bundle that includes the fix, the container will unregister the old bundle and register the new bundle. The proxy can then handle the reference shuffling and resume the service invocation.  This interaction will be almost instantaneous. Your customers will be completely oblivious to what has happened and you just saved your company a substantial amount of money (do I hear bonus?).

In this blog post, the call to authorizePayment() was put on hold until the updated bundle is available. What happens if the control is within the authorizePayment() method when bundle refresh happens?

Answer (score 21):

Bundles have 2 kind of dependencies:

- Services, and
- Connections between
  class loaders, keyed by the package
  names. Those connections are called
  wires.

Services are easy to withdraw because that is intrinsic to their design. Wires are harder because they are intricately woven in your objects and those objects are not aware of the dynamics. So when you install a new bundle, the old bundles stay as they are, your objects are not updated and the updated bundle still provides its wires as a zombie.

When you call refreshPackages the framework looks at those dependencies and finds the bundles that refer to those zombies. Every zombie is then stopped. The contract for a bundle is that it should cleanup. We help the bundle by doing a lot of cleanup for you, but some things are very bad, e.g. storing references in statics of other bundles or forgetting to stop threads that were started. Other bundles that depend in other ways on those bundles get notified of the bundle stopping so they can also clean up any references. After the bundles are stopped, the bundles are unresolved and then resolved again against the new bundles.

For real OSGi bundles the cleaning up is natural and not really visible in your code (as it should be). It is well supported by the tools like Declarative services, iPOJO, dependency manager, Spring, Blueprint, etc. The magic is focus on the µservices model and not dong class loading hacks.

Why are we not refreshing automatically? Well, we once did but refreshing is disruptive. In many cases you need to update multiple bundles. Having this disruption after each update would be unnecessary painful. That is, after an install or update you should ALWAYS do a refresh but you can bracket a number of installs/updates.

Comment: If I install a new minor version of an API bundle (a bundle not containing executable code) it could be desirable not to refresh bundles depending on a previous version because they don't need that to work and it is disruptive. Is it true or your ALWAYS is absolute?

Comment: Pretty much ... since you won't release the uninstalled bundles due to links from other bundles you will quickly build up a rats nest. I am always concerned about the argument to prevent disruption. Any system can fail due to power so you _must_ have a solution to handle this disruption without causing fatalities. So the small disruption of a bundle refresh can by definition not be a big problem. My strategy is do it right then optimize. Imho preventing some small disruption does not weigh up to the fact that you leave the framework in an undefined state.

Comment: I want to install minor API versions without uninstalling previous ones. The outdated bundles would be useful to avoid unnecessary bundle restarts. My management agent should have, of course, a way to detect this outdated bundles and uninstall them on the next restart but, if using import ranges, it would be more convenient than strictly necessary because no bundle would be wired to them. I don't see the undefined state here and still thinking I'm doing the right (and optimal) thing but, as Descartes said, "I would give everything I know for half of what I ignore" so ... where's the mind bug?

Comment: At last, but not least, another simpler exception to the rule are pure implementation bundles (bundles providing only services). Refresh would be useless in that case because there's nothing needing to be refreshed. I hope not being too much picky about all of this because I'm in love with the idea of living in a world without refresh

Answer (score 9):

When you update a bundle, using the OSGi '***update***' command, it is most likely to have other dependent bundles that are relying on it and already capturing a set of loaded classes from the old version of this bundle. A situation that typically conforms to the problem you described in your question.

In order to avoid possible inconsistency between the different versions of the classes enfolded by this bundle, the OSGi container decides to temporarily hide the new version of the updated bundle's classes from the outside world. You can think of it as kind of keeping the updated classes in isolation from the other bundles -*momentarily*-.

The point here is that the OSGi container can’t just start loading classes from the new version of the target bundle, because the dependent bundles would end up seeing old versions of the classes they already loaded, mixed with new versions of the same classes that were loaded after the update, which would incorporate an inconsistency that would result in an uncontrollable mess. The same goes for the bundle Uninstall, the bundle is removed from the installed list of bundles, but it is not removed from memory. It shall be kept around so that dependent bundles can continue to load classes from it.

So you can think of the 'update' command, as introducing a new version of the same bundle, to be **only** supplied to dependent bundles that are yet to come, -which are not yet there at the time of the update-. While the old version -that existed before the update-, remains *in memory* in order to assure backward compatibility and avoid any possible disruption to existing bundles that have already started to depend on the updated bundle.

*Note, that the old versions are only kept in memory, which means that a restart to the server will result in eradicating all these old versions and bring the latest version to the table. This makes perfect sense, because there will be no need for backward compatibility, simply because all bundles are now starting at the same time..*

What happens next, is that you have to explicitly invoke the '***refresh***' command on specific bundles, -those which are depending on the updated bundle-, or instead you can choose to run the 'refresh' command without specifying a specific bundle, meaning that all bundles will be blindly refreshed. The 'refresh' command forces the rebuilding of the dependency tree of the target bundles, and coerce their class loaders to start loading their required classes from scratch.

**Only then dependent bundles will start to see the changes you have made to the code of the classes living in the bundle that has been updated.**

The rule is that

> Existing resolved bundles already importing an older version of a class won’t be automatically rewired to the new bundle unless they’re refreshed.

Answer (score 6):

When a bundle is updated, a new revision (the bits of the bundle) is installed. If another bundle is wired to the prior revision of the updated bundle, that is, another bundle imported some package exported by the prior revision or another bundle required the bundle at the prior revision, then the OSGi framework will retain the prior revision of the updated bundle to service future class load requests from the dependent bundle until a bundle refresh occurs which includes the dependent bundle.

The purpose of this is to minimize or delay perturbing dependent bundles when a dependency is updated. A management agent may want to update several bundles and, at the end, do a bundle refresh to "modernize" the dependencies. Once the bundle refresh is done, there are no wires to the prior revision of the updated bundle and the OSGi framework is now free to discard the prior revision.

So in your example, generally no exception will result. But of course it depends upon what the code in question is actually doing and how their bundle manifests are written.